# Maven and webstart project how to test using jetty?

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a Maven project and I have integrated the [webstart-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/usage.html). The jnlp gets generated and I would like to test it by deploying it into to jetty but haven't found any jetty goals to achieve that. Is there an automated way to test the jnlp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using `webstart-maven-plugin` for a while until I realized it just fills a jnlp template and copies jar files.

Now, I'm using a static jnlp (stored in `src/main/webapp/applet`) and `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the jar(s):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>applet-copy</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>applet.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>applet-artifact-id</artifactId>
                                <version>x.y.z</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <destFileName>applet.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/web-resources/applet</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It actually copies the applet into `target/web-resources/applet`. Then I just need to add this directory as web resource in the `jetty-maven-plugin`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                    <resourceBases>
                        <resourceBase>${project.build.directory}/web-resources</resourceBase>
                    </resourceBases>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And add it into the war:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/web-resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope it helps.

By the way, you can find more information about `jetty-maven-plugin` configuration [on this page](http://www.benoitschweblin.com/2013/03/run-jetty-in-maven-life-cycle.html).